# Convergent subsequence built from other subsequences

Tags: limits

I want to build a convergent subsequence from two subsequences. Let $%
\{n_{1_{l}}\}_{l=1}^{\infty }$ and $\{n_{2_{l}}\}_{l=1}^{\infty }$\ be
increasing sequences of integers, not necessarily disjoint. Let $\{x_{n}\}$
have subsequences $\{x_{n_{1_{l}}}\}_{l=1}^{\infty }$ and $%
\{x_{n_{2_{l}}}\}_{l=1}^{\infty }$ with $\lim_{l\rightarrow \infty
}x_{n_{1_{l}}}$ $=$ $a$ and $\lim_{l\rightarrow \infty }x_{n_{2_{l}}}$ $=$ $a
$. Now build a new index set $\tilde{n}_{l}$ by intertwining unique values
from $\{n_{1_{l}},n_{2_{l}}\}$. For example, $\{n_{1_{l}}\}$ $=$ $%
\{1,5,6,100,...\}$ and $\{n_{2_{l}}\}$ $=$ $\{1,5,56,90,...\}$ hence $\{%
\tilde{n}_{l}\}$ $=$ $\{n_{1_{l}}\}\cup \{n_{2_{l}}\}$ $=$ $%
\{1,5,6,56,90,100,...\}$. Then is $\lim_{l\rightarrow \infty }x_{\tilde{n}_{l}}$
$=$ $a$?

I cannot locate a matching thread here, and my apologies if other threads
implicitly cover this. My argument is as follows. By convergence of the
subsequences, $\forall \varepsilon $ $>$ $0$ $\exists (\mathcal{L}%
_{1,\varepsilon },\mathcal{L}_{2,\varepsilon })$ $\in $ $\mathbb{N}$ such
that
\begin{equation*}
\left\vert x_{n_{1_{l}}}-a\right\vert \leq \varepsilon \text{ }\forall l\geq
\mathcal{L}_{1,\varepsilon }\text{ and }\left\vert
x_{n_{2_{l}}}-a\right\vert \leq \varepsilon \text{ }\forall l\geq \mathcal{L}_{2,\varepsilon }.
\end{equation*}

Now pick $\mathcal{L}_{\varepsilon }$ $=$ $\max \{\mathcal{L}_{1,\varepsilon
},\mathcal{L}_{2,\varepsilon }\}$ to yield for the intertwined sequence $|x_{%
\tilde{n}_{l}}$ $-$ $a|$ $\leq $ $\varepsilon $ $\forall l$ $\geq $ $%
\mathcal{L}_{\varepsilon }$. Therefore $x_{\tilde{n}_{l}}$ $\rightarrow $ $a$.

Comments are appreciated.